# Click on second element found - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, onclick

I have following element that I wanna ckick on:

```
<a class="" style="background-image:url(/images/icons/folder_page.png)" onclick="showIndicator('Dokumente werden geladen...');" href="/masterdata/showDocuments/id/1">Dokumente</a>
```

by using

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Dokumente")
```

However, there is another element with the same name, that is found and clicked first.
Its html is:

```
<a onclick="showIndicator(&quot;Dokumente werden geladen...&quot;)" href="/document">Dokumente</a>
```

How can I select the second element that is found?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the links id's:

```
<a id="Dokumente-1" class="" style="background-image:url(/images/icons/folder_page.png)" onclick="showIndicator('Dokumente werden geladen...');" href="/masterdata/showDocuments/id/1">Dokumente</a>

<a id="Dokumente-2" onclick="showIndicator(&quot;Dokumente werden geladen...&quot;)" href="/document">Dokumente</a>
```

then use this to find them:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("Dokumente-1")
```

Comment: Interesting but I think this ain't gonna help me. I wanna scrape hundreds of different pages (all have this button). So I would need to place the id on each of those pages....

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. But thank you :)

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@style='background-image:url(/images/icons/folder_page.png)']").click()
```